# Range of MPI_offset in MPI

Tags: c, types, mpi

I am using MPI2.2 standard to write parallel program in C. I have 64 bit machine.

```
/* MPI offset is long long*/

MPI_Offset my_offset; printf ("%3d: my offset = %lld\n", my_rank, my_offset);

int count; 
MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_BYTE, &count);

printf ("%3d: read =%d\n", my_rank, count);
```

I am reading a file of very large size byte by byte. To read the file parallely i am setting the offset for each process using offset variable. I am having confusion for the data-type of MPI_offset type, that `"whither it is signed or unsigned"` long ?

My second question is about limitation of the "range of count variable" which is used in MPI_Get_count() function. since this function is used here to read all the elements from each process's buffer `so i think it should also be of the long long type to read such a very large file.`

Comment: Is this file on a hard disk? You do realize that trying to read a file in parallel like that is likely going to be much slower than having a single reader.

Comment: yes file is on a disk. I am using MPICH2 parallel I/O to read the file parallely by chunk of "total number of bytes / NP " size. where NP is the number of processes to create.

Comment: @Janne: If you have the hardware and a filesystem designed for parallel IO such as Lustre, it can certainly be much faster. This is common in HPC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MPI_Offset`'s size isn't defined by the standard - it is, roughly, as large as possible. ROMIO, a widely-used underlying implemetation of MPI-IO, uses 8-byte integers on systems which support them. You can probably find out for sure by looking in your system's mpi.h.

MPI_Offset is very definitely signed; there are functions like MPI_File_seek where it is perfectly reasonable to have values of type MPI_Offset take negative values.

MPI_Get_count returns an integer, of normal integer size, and this can certainly cause problems for some large file IO strategies.

Generally, it's better for a number of reasons not to use small low-level units of IO like bytes when doing MPI-IO; it's better in terms of performance and code readability to express the IO in units of your underlying data types.  In doing so, these size limitations become less of an issue.    If your underlying data type really is bytes, though, thre aren't many options.

Comment: I have a file of size 40GB, containing a string of maximum 30bytes in each line. And i am using  MPI_File_read(fh, read_buffer, chunk, MPI_BYTE, &status); to read by each process. IS there any other level of units to read it to have better performance?

Comment: Oof, that's a tough one; I remember you asking about a version of this before, I think.   I think the answer is no, there isn't a better way given the file you have.  If you know the file has records of maximum 30 bytes, is it feasible for you to run a one-time conversion to make sure every record has exactly 30 bytes (eg, just pad the short lines) and then use MPI-IO on that?  You'd pay a one-time conversion cost, but the operations on the fixed-record-length file would then be much faster and simpler.

Comment: Version 2.2 of the standard says, that `MPI_Offset` should be an integer of the size needed to hold any valid file size on the target architecture. Then the standard goes on to define that the "external32" representation of `MPI_Offset` should be 8 bytes long. Go figure.

Comment: I have a grid with >10^9 cells, my unit is thus the number of cells, with 32bit indices I can only read 4*10^9 cells, anything else overflows `MPI_Offset`...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to interleave MPI_File_read with something like MPI_File_seek(mpiFile,mpiOffset,MPI_SEEK_CUR ) ? This way you may succeed to avoid MPI_Offset overflow